# Regex: Trying to modify accented sentences, using unaccented keywords

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to modify accented sentences using unaccented keywords in order to make those words bold.

So here is how my problem split.

1 - I have **accented and unaccented** sentences (I have both of them available, but would prefer to keep only accented in memory) such as for example:

- accented version: *"C'est au neuvième étage"*
- unaccented version: *"C'est au neuvieme etage"*

2 - I have **unaccented** keywords:

- *"neuvieme"*
- *"etage"*

3 - I try to obtain the following **accented result**: *"C'est au [b]neuvième[/b] [b]étage[/b]"*

I can find "complex" solution, but I am unable at that point to find if I can achieve this in a more straightforward manner using regex. I am searching this way, because I need it to be fast.

If anybody have an idea about this, I would be glad to read it.

Thank you.

---

Edit for solution.

The ideas suggested by Qtex works.

I used the following patterns with preg_replace:

```
$pattern = array( "'a'","'c'","'e'","'i'","'n'","'o'","'u'","'y'" );

$replace = array( "(a|à|á|â|ã|ä|A|À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä)",
                  "(c|ç|C|Ç)",
                  "(e|è|é|ê|ë|E|È|É|Ê|Ë)",
                  "(i|ì|í|î|ï|I|Ì|Í|Î|Ï)",
                  "(n|ñ|N|Ñ)",
                  "(o|ò|ó|ô|õ|ö|O|Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ö)",
                  "(u|ù|ú|û|ü|U|Ù|Ú|Û|Ü)",
                  "(y|ý|ÿ|Y|Ý)");
```

I had to separate them using the pipe character instead of grouping them into square brackets, because the accented characters turns to be in fact multiple characters each... so it doesn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple straightforward solution would be to in your keywords replace:

- `a` with `[aáà]`
- `e` with `[eéè]`
- etc for all the accented characters you want to handle

And then use the new keywords in a regex to match and replace:

```
preg_replace('/f[oóò][oóò]|b[aáà]r/i', '[b]$0[/b]', $str)
```

Comment: This idea is very interesting, and doesn't seems too difficult or costly. I will give it a try.